# Obtaining FB password with users permission

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to obtain a users fb password, with granted permission?
I'm using it in a project that allows users to keep their sensitive data locked using their fb account. 
It's for an iOS application, and right now I'm able to collect a users email, through the Facebook iOS sdk, and password, through a login "workaround", but I'm not sure if the app is going to get rejected due to infringement of facebook's and or apple's legal rights.

Comment: think of it like a Facebook login sheet, where a user has to type in fb - email and password in order to get access to their data. But is it legal to obtain the password through a workaround?

Comment: You don't need the password and you shouldn't steal it. If the FB account login is validated then you can allow access...

Comment: I appreciate your reply, obtaining a users password the way I had intended is illegal, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is **not possible** to obtain a user's Facebook password.
I am not sure if the app will be rejected but I would personally avoid this solution.

I suggest to use the user's `facebookId` instead of the user's email.

**If the secured data are stored in the app:**

You only need the `facebookId`.

---

**If the secured data are stored on a server:**

Of course, checking only the `facebookId` isn't secure enough because anyone with a precise `facebookId` could login with it and get access to the "secured" data on your server.

What you need is two parameter to identify a user through your app:

- The **`facebookId`** of the user
- A **secret key**

You can send the **secret key** in your header request (or as a `URL`/`BODY` parameter if you want). It ensures that your server is called by your app an not from another source (a hacker).

What I would do to be more secure is to **hash** these two parameters in SHA1 so that even your request isn't readable. Then all you have to do is compare on your server the same key hashed in SHA1 with the one received.

For hashing a string to SHA1, here is a link : http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/how-to-get-md5-and-sha1-in-objective-c-ios-sdk/